# HTML Simple Holding Page not visible on newer browsers e.g. Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html

I want to update an existing/simple holding page on my domain in html.

Unfortunately, I've noticed that this page doesn't seem to appear on newer browsers such as Chrome and Firefox and only seems to load up properly on Internet Explorer.

Is there any advice you could give me to help overcome this issue please?

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>"TITLE HERE"</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body style="background:ffffff url('LOGO.jpg') no-repeat center center">
</a>
</body>
</html>
<!--#easybanner4-->
```

Comment: You're missing the # before ffffff

Comment: Also remove the stray `</a>` - not that it's causing the issue.

Comment: Guys I can't thank you enough :)

Comment: also, is it OK to remove the follow: <!--#easybanner4-->  and also <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> ? after this i will hang my head in shame :P

Comment: Yes, just use `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a simple HTML page visible by most modern browsers it's better to use HTML5 so first, instead of using `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">` just use `<!DOCTYPE html>`...

About your code, you can fix it by using something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- or <meta charset="iso-8859-1"> -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>"TITLE HERE"</title>

  <style>
    body {
    background:#ffffff url('LOGO.jpg') no-repeat center fixed;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="#">link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks using this code is excellent but the logo picture isn't centred vertically :(

Comment: I just used your setting, now edited it to make it centered with  `background-attachment: fixed;`

Comment: Thanks man; much appreciated. Also thanks for your patience :)